# How to add a carousel to an ember site

Tags: ember.js

I would like to add a carousel, preferably caroufredsel http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/, to a few templates/routes on an ember site. I was wondering what the best way to do that would be?

All that is needed to fire the items that you want to slide is the following jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo1").carouFredSel();
});
```

Where do you think the best place in the app to put this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place it to create a custom `View` for the template that will have the carousel.  Then use the `didInsertElement` hook to initialize the widget once the markup for the carousel once it is in the document.  You can also use the `willDestroyElement` hook to tear down the carousel before the markup is removed from the document.

So, say that you have a `/carousel` route, and then you have this as your `'carousel'` template.

```
<div id="foo1">
    <!-- Other carousel markup goes here-->
</div>
```

Then you'd create a `View` like this.

```
App.CarouselView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    $("#foo1").carousel();
  },
  willDestroyElement : function(){
    $("#foo1").trigger("destroy");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works well except the carousel is breaking on redirect. Any idea why? Thank you! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988874/carousel-breaking-on-initial-redirect-but-works-properly-on-refresh