# Carousel breaking on initial redirect, but works properly on refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a nav bar with an 'About' link. When clicked it should bring up a subnav and redirect you to 'about.philosophy' rather than 'about.index', which it does.

I have a carousel partial I'm rendering on the about.hbs template:

```
<div class="row about-bg">
    {{partial 'about/about-carousel'}}
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

That is being fired in the AboutView:

```
Ew.AboutView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#about-carousel").carouFredSel({
            responsive: true,
            width: "100%",
            height: 'variable',
            items: {
            height: 'variable'
            }
        });
    });
   }
});
```

However, when the 'About' link is first clicked, changing the url to '/about/philosophy', the carousel is broken -- all the images just stacked on top of one another and no movement -- like the js isn't being found or something. But as soon as I hit refresh on my browser the carousel renders fine. It must be the redirect that is breaking it, because it works fine on refresh when ember isn't firing the redirect.

The redirect function, along with subnav rendering code is in AboutIndexRoute:

```
Ew.AboutIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function(){
    this.controllerFor('application').set('renderAboutSubNav', true);
  },
  deactivate: function(){
    this.controllerFor('application').set('renderAboutSubNav', false);
  },
  redirect: function(){
    this.transitionTo('about.philosophy');
  }
});
```

The subnav is also failing to display.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$(window).load(function() {});` wrapper from your `didInsertElement` method.

Comment: That does fix that problem, however, I added the `$(window).load(function() {});` because without it, the div occupied by the slider is empty until the first image slides in. Without it the first image of the slider doesn't show until the first movement. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your problem. Could you clarify? Even better - could you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: I'm sorry...so what is happening is that the carousel is responsive and housed inside a div that doesn't have a specific height set on it -- because it is responsive. So the height of the carousel container is `0px` until an image "slides" in to give that container actual height. So for some reason, without `$(window).load(function() {});` the first image in the collection is not visible -- resulting in the container having `height: 0px`. Only when the second image in the collection moves in to view -- the first actual sliding movement -- does the container get height and become visible.

Comment: Ah I see, but that's hard to say without being able to debug code directly. Have you tried calling the `updateSizes` method?